# Webbit server not working properly in android app

Tags: android, java-websocket

I'm trying to server an HTML file to users who are connected on the same network using the webbit library.

**This is what I expect:**

Pressing a button in the android app to start the HTTP server (HTML file is under assets/web/index.html)
Any of the same network users would be able to browse that HTML using the local IP of the phone like 192.168.0.xxx:8080 (or any other port used in implementation)

**This is how I tried:**

```
WebServer webServer = WebServers.createWebServer(8080)
                    .add("/mysocket", new HelloWebSockets())
                    .add(new StaticFileHandler("web"));
            webServer.start();
```

I ran the app and started the server and tried to visit the page but I got

> PAGE NOT FOUND 404

Help will be much appreciated. If the question is not clear please comment. Thanks.

Comment: Which url is used by the browser?

Comment: `PAGE NOT FOUND 404`. Not very informative. Which page is not found?

Comment: 192.168.0.179:8080

Comment: @blackapps there is only one index.html page there.

Comment: Ok. But i asked wich url you used. You should ask for the page itself and use `http://192.168.0.179:8080/index.htm` or `https://192.168.0.179:8080/index.html`.

Comment: `HTML file is under assets/web/index.html` How did you tell your server that that file is there?